# Speed up update in large table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a table with 128 million records. There are no foreign keys or indexes, just a heap table. I need to update 3 fields in all the records based on a logic that depends on other fields in the same table. It takes ~1 hour to complete.

Is there any way to speed up this update?

This is the DDL:

```
create table table_1
(
    Column_1 int  NOT NULL,
    Column_2 int  NOT NULL,
    Column_3 smallint  NULL,
    Column_4 int  NULL,
    Column_5 smallint  NOT NULL,
    Column_6 bit  NOT NULL,
    Column_7 bit  NOT NULL,
    Column_8 int  NULL,
    Column_9 int  NULL,
    Column_10 varchar  NULL,
    Column_11 varchar  NULL,
    Column_12 varchar  NULL,
    Column_13 int  NULL,
    Column_14 bit  NOT NULL,
    Column_15 uniqueidentifier  NULL,
    Column_16 uniqueidentifier  NULL,
    Column_17 int  NOT NULL,
    Column_18 int  NOT NULL,
    Column_19 int  NOT NULL,
    Column_20 smalldatetime  NULL,
    Column_21 int  NULL,
    Column_22 smalldatetime  NULL,
    Column_23 smalldatetime  NULL,
    Column_24 int  NULL,
    Column_25 smalldatetime  NULL,
    Column_26 int  NULL,
    Column_27 datetime  NULL,
    Column_28 nvarchar  NULL,
    Column_29 bit  NOT NULL,
    Column_30 bit  NOT NULL,
    Column_31 int  NULL,
    Column_32 int  NULL,
    Column_33 int  NULL,
    Column_34 int  NULL,
    Column_35 int  NULL,
    Column_36 bit  NULL,
    Column_37 int  NULL,
    Column_38 int  NULL,
    Column_39 bit  NULL,
    Column_40 int  NULL,
    Column_41 datetimeoffset  NULL,
    Column_42 int  NULL,
    Column_43 datetime  NULL,
    Column_44 char  NULL)
```

This is the update:

```
update table1
set  
    Column_34 = Column_31,
    Column_35 = Column_32,
    Column_37 = Column_33
```

Comment: A few questions that would make answering easier:

How many rows are you trying to update? 
Are you updating all at once or in batches? 
Can you add indexes to speed up finding the rows to update?

Comment: All of them, I need to update 3 fields in every single record in the table.

Comment: Add your table DDL (including PK definition) and the update query to your question.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, it's a heap table without a primary key. I inherited that from legacy old code (~10 years). I couldn't  even find a good candidate key, it's just "historical" data. (Column_1, Column_43, Column_44) is the closest to a candidate key but there are some duplicated though.

Comment: Maybe a different perspective could help here, after reviewing your `UPDATE` statement why do you want to have two columns with the same exact data between them?...What is your ultimate goal with these other columns you're trying to update?

Comment: This seems like a one-time execution - so why is there a need to optimize it? You know how long it currently takes so you have run it once already. And obviously you should update rows that need no changes. If column_34 should always be the same as column_31, why not guarantee that using a computed column? Rename the existing column if needed to avoid dropping the column.

Comment: @SMor precisely my thoughts and why I'm questioning OP's root goal here. Having two columns in the same table with the same exact values rarely makes sense.

Comment: @SMor absolutely, you are right, but I have a limited execution window and this is part of a migration that implies some schema changes.

Comment: @J.D. after this script, I will drop columns 31, 32 and 33.

Comment: @YvánEcarri Why not just rename the old columns to the new names instead?...or at least take up SMor's suggestion of just adding a computed column? You can easily rename columns either using SSMS or by calling the system stored procedure [`sp_rename`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/rename-columns-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15#to-rename-a-column) which should be pretty instantaneous since it's just a metadata change.

Comment: @J.D. I need these columns in this exact order and they must be updatable. There is another piece of code doing a INSERT FROM SELECT and it expects this table to have exactly the structure shown. Yes, I know it is a bad practice to INSERT FROM SELECT without a column list but that code is autogenerated and I don't have any control or authority to change it.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`sp_rename`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-rename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) per my suggestion in the comments almost meets all of your requirements of leaving the columns in the same order and keeps them updatable, in addition to being an *instantaneous* change.

It looks like the only snag is you want to move `Column_33` (which will now be called `Column_37`) to after `Column_36`, i.e. you want to change the previous column order for that specific column, agreed?

Alternatively you could create a View on top of the Table with the schema fixes you want instead, which would also be updatable and instantaneous.